# What is the domain of the following function?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Please tell me the domain of $y = \sin^{-1}(\sin(x))$

P.S. I think domain is $(-\infty, \infty)$ But my teacher says it is $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$. He says since $sine$ is a many one function, so its domain has to be confined in the interval of $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ to make it an inverse function. Well I didn't quite understand. Please explain.

Comment: I think you're right.

Comment: what is the domain of $\sin^{-1}$?

Comment: It is [-1, 1]. Why?

Comment: I second Gerry's comment. I think you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the graph might do some help.

[image]

Comment: So the domain **is** all Real Numbers, no?

Comment: yes. precisely. The graph clearly shows.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder if my teacher agrees. He is bit too egoist. Thank you anyways.

Comment: You are right whether your teacher agrees or not. Your teacher's ego is irrelevant.